# save to a point cloud file

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know how to save a point cloud msg to a point cloud file?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29222/save-to-a-point-cloud-file/) by [bona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1158/bona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2012-03-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[pointcloud_to_pcd](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros#pointcloud_to_pcd)

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3